# Field Collection, with Entity Reference, can get value

Tags: entities

I've got a field collection, which contains

1. A copy field
2. A user field, via entity reference

Now when I try to access the copy field by storing the collection in `$collection`, via

```
$collection->field_my_collection_copy->value();
```

I get what im looking for, but trying similar on the entity referenced field

```
$collection->field_my_collection_user->value();
```

It breaks. By looking into the variables for `$collection->field_my_collection_user` I should have 'uid' available on it, but `$collection->field_my_collection_user->uid` gives me nothing and `$collection->field_my_collection_user->uid->value();` gives me `Unable to get the data property uid as the parent data structure is not set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, I should've given the anonymous user the privilege to view the data.